# Add JarFile to Classpath at runtime in Java 14

Tags: java, classpath

Hey how can i add a jar to the classpath at runtime with java 14+? I tried to cast the SystemClassLoader as URLClassLoader as i saw in some examples, but it throws a ClassCastException. Is there anyone who know how i can a the jar to the classpath in newer java versions?

Comment: Often, dynamic loading of classes is best done using [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Answer (score 1):

"Add to the system classpath at runtime" is, as a concept, generally unsupported. There can be various unsupported (in that it relies on e.g. something public being a subclass of something, even though the spec makes no such guarantees) hacks to make that work, but the keyword there is **unsupported**. There is a very high maintenance burden and should therefore be used only as last resort. In this case, there is no reason to do so; there are far better options available.

i.e. you are asking an X/Y problem. You have some unstated problem and you thought: I know! I'll add a jar to the classpath at runtime! And now you're asking question about how to do that.

But the error is in the "I know! I'll add a jar to the classpath at runtime" part. That's wrong.

### Okay, so what's right?

Simply make a new classloader, that has the system classloader as parent. You're clearly dynamically loading things here, so make sure you do this in the right context. (That is, don't run e.g. `Class.forName("foo.bar")`, instead run `thatClassLoaderYouMadeForThis.loadClass()` instead).

A tricky thing is the following process:

- A ClassLoader, by default (you can override this default with a custom implementation, but that makes things rather complicated), will *first* ask its parent loader to load a thing, and will only actually load the class itself if the parent **cannot** find it.
- A class will load any of its dependencies (any types that are used inside it) using its own classloader. If that classloader can't find it, you get errors.

In other words, if you have, say, this class:

```
class MyClassA {
   MyClassB b;
}
```

as well as `class MyClassB extends MyClassA {}`, and `MyClassA` is available on your system classpath (so, can just get loaded), and `MyClassB` is not, so you are loading it with a child classloader, then **that does not work** - the act of loading `MyClassB` will cause `MyClassA` to be loaded, but as the parent classloader (being the system classloader) **does** know where to find `MyClassA`, it becomes MyClassA's loader, and thus it will be asked to load `MyClassB` in order to make sense of that field it has, and this will fail, as the system loader doesn't know how to do that. But this is quite a bizarre scenario - how did you end up in a scenario where you have a class file (`MyClassA.class`) that was compiled with access to `MyClassB`, but MyClassB is no longer part of either the same jar file `myClassA` is in, or in general the same classpath conditions?

So, usually, this isn't a problem, but it's good to be aware of how this works.

With that out of the way:

```
URLClassLoader myLoader = new URLCLassLoader(new URL[] {
  new URL(Paths.get("/path/to/my/custom/lib.jar").toUri().toURL()});

myLoader.loadClass("com.foo.whateverYouWantedToLoad");
```

Comment: OK thank you, but how can I load a class without knowing there name like dependencies or on a module system when I load modules/plugins like for example minecraft servers?

Comment: .. did you see the snippet at the end? `"com.foo.whateverYouWanted"` is a string, you can pass user input there just the same way. A `Class<?>` object is produced from it. Check the API for what you can do with this. You can invoke methods on it, constructors, get fields, etc.

Comment: Yes i saw it, but how can i add the jar without knowing the class. For example if i need a specific lib without a main class, only with Utils?

Comment: Obviously you can't do that then.  You need to have the jar, know where it is, and know the name of the class you want to load.

Comment: I found a possibility to load the jar without knowing the classes. Thank You

Comment: @Infinity_dev hey, do you mind posting the solution that you found? I would like to know how to do it as well.